# Change href and src of an img onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, href, src

I'm trying to find a solution to my JS problem, but impossible ! I want to change the source of an img onclick, and the href too. On the second click, we go to the link of the new href.

It's like : First image with no link -> Click on it -> Second Image and a new link -> Click on it -> go to the page of this new link.

This is my code :

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    $('.menulink').click(function(){
    $("#bg").attr('src',"<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>
        /Images/
        second.png");
        $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
        return false;
        });
        });
```

HTML

```
<a href="" title="Website" class="menulink"><img src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/Images/first.png" id="bg"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only run the event handler once per `.menulink`, otherwise it will return false every time and never follow the link.  So you can loop through with `.each` and then use `.one` to bind, this way the *first* click will run the javascript, which sets the `href` attribute.  And the *second* click will just be clicking a normal link.

```
$(function() {
    $('.menulink').each(function() {
        $(this).one("click", function(){
            $("#bg").attr('src',"<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/Images/second.png");
            $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```